# How to compute $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k}{z^k} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I need to compute:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k}{z^k}  $$

Can someone help me?

Comment: So this is a geometric progression ...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} r^k=\frac{1}{1-r},\quad |r|<1.$$ Here $r=\dfrac{4}{z}$ for appropriate $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=\dfrac 4 z$, and $s$ be the sum. Then $r s = s-1$ and so $s = \dfrac 1 {1-r}$.